# I'm trying to write a program called oddsUpTo that returns an array with every odd number up to a given digit

Tags: javascript, arrays, count

I'm trying to get into a bootcamp and this is a problem I'm clearly missing something on. I know I'm missing something obvious but I'm having trouble spotting it. Here's what I have so far:

```js
function oddsUpTo(num) {
  let arr = [];
  for (let i = 1; i <= num; i += 2) {
    if (num[i] % 2 === 1) {
      arr.push(num[i]);
    }
  }
  return arr;
}
console.log(oddsUpTo(20)) // should equal[1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19]
```

Comment: Why the check? If you start at 1 (`let i = 1`), and keep adding 2 (`i += 2`), it is always odd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `num` is number not an array. Please try this way.

```js
function oddsUpTo(num) {
    let arr = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= num; i += 2) {
        arr.push(i);
    }
    return arr;
}
console.log(oddsUpTo(20));
```

Hope it works.